# Can I use a server to connect multiple peppers using Qisession()?

Tags: pepper

I successfully connected a pepper running a behavior and communicated with it using java-scripts hosted on a web server.  Functions used included Qisession and ALMemory.subscriber.

Can the web server connect more than one pepper at the same time?
Can peppers communicate with each others through the web server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's totally possible, you can have one qisession per robot and then use that to orchestrate their common behavior.

Comment: I don't have any doing specifically that. Maybe you can try doing it and come back with more precise questions if you can't get it to work...